# How to export an array from a DLL?

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, dllexport

**I can`t export an array from a DLL.** Here is my code:

**" DLL header "**

```
#ifdef EXPORT
    #define MYLIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
    #define MYLIB
#endif


extern "C" {
/* Allows to use file both with Visual studio and with Qt*/
#ifdef __cplusplus
    MYLIB double MySum(double num1, double num2);
    extern MYLIB char ImplicitDLLName[]; 
#else
    extern Q_DECL_IMPORT char ImplicitDLLName[]; 
    Q_DECL_IMPORT double MySum(double num1, double num2);
#endif
}
```

**" DLL source"**

```
 #define EXPORT
    #include "MySUMoperator.h"

    double MySum(double num1, double num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    char ImplicitDLLName[] = "MySUMOperator";
```

**" client main.cpp"**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%s", ImplicitDLLName);
}
```

**When building I am getting from the linker this error:**

```
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImplicitDLLName  \Client\main.obj
```

// My purpose of exporting the array is to study export of different data structs from DLLs

**How to cope with the error raised by linker and what rules are violated?**

**UPDATE:  ** 
IDE Visual Studio 2010.
Client - is written on C++, also DLL is on C++

Comment: I think you need to put MYLIB at the array *definition*.

Comment: @n.m. After you suggested - I have tried, it is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're linking your import library correctly (and thats a *big* assumption), you're not declaring MYLIB correctly for importing symbols:

This:

```
#ifdef EXPORT
    #define MYLIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
    #define MYLIB
#endif
```

Should be this:

```
#ifdef EXPORT
    #define MYLIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
    #define MYLIB __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Keep in mind we've little context to work with. It *looks* like you're trying to consume this from a C-compiled application, but without more info I can't be sure. If that is the case, then Q_DECL_IMPORT had better do the above or it still will not work. I'd start with a basic "C" linkage export and work your way up from there.

---

**Sample EXPORTS.DLL**

Exports.h

```
#ifdef EXPORTS_EXPORTS
#define EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" EXPORTS_API char szExported[];
```

Exports.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Exports.h"

// This is an example of an exported variable
EXPORTS_API char szExported[] = "Exported from our DLL";
```

**Sample EXPORTSCLIENT.EXE**

ExportsClient.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Exports.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << szExported << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Exported from our DLL
```

Comment: Thanks for response.I also got functions in my dll and they are exported successfully so I can use them from the client. To check if array is exported I use dumpbin /exports mydllName.dll and it says that the array is exported.As far as I know statement __declspec(dllimport) is optional and can be ommited.

Comment: @spin_eight I've tried compiling without it in the past and no-joy on external *variables* from my experience. Compiling the above sample without dllimport specc'ed I receive the same undefined reference in your question. Thus the reason I always use it. It is also conceivable the problem on your end may be a "C" linkage issue. I'd look at that as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, the case was in  that I ommited __declspec(dllimport) in clients header. When debugging my code I was reluctant to try to insert __declspec(dllimport) statement due to in My university teacher insisted that this statement is optional and only meant to made easier linkers work. So from that moment I shall double check that teachers statements. Are there any dll standarts, so actually where I can find info that __declspec(dllimport) is obligatory, how you have figured that out???

Comment: The best example I can give for how you *should* do it is to follow Microsoft's boilerplate sample code, which is all I really did when generating the above sample. It is no mistake that import/export is included on both functions *and* variables.